# SQLite for Windows Phone - release any CPU

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I want to release an Windows Phone 8.1 App for "any CPU". It works with SQLite which gives me the error that this reference doesn't support Any CPU and only x86 or ARM will work.
Is there any workaround or possibility to still release the App for "Any CPU"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no workaround. As soon as you use a native library, which is the case for SQLite, you need to submit your app built for ARM. For the emulator you have to use x86. But as all Windows Phones are ARM based there's no need to submit an Any CPU build.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some research showed, that releasing for "Any CPU" is not needed. "ARM" is enough to submit the app to the store.